# Merge lines with same ID and take average value

Tags: r

From the table below I need to combine the lines by calculating the average value for those lines with same ID (column 2). 
I was thinking of the `plyr` function??

```
ddply(df, summarize, value = average(ID))
```

df:

```
      miRNA      ID  100G  100R 106G  106R  122G  122R 124G  124R  126G 126R  134G  134R 141G  141R 167G 167R 185G  185R
1   hsa-miR-106a ID7 1585   423  180   113   598   266  227   242    70  106  2703   442  715   309  546  113  358   309
2 hsa-miR-1185-1 ID2   10     1    3     3    11     8    4     4    28    2    13     3    6     3    6    4    7     5
3 hsa-miR-1185-2 ID2    2     0    2     1     5     1    1     0     4    1     1     1    3     2    2    0    2     1
4   hsa-miR-1197 ID2    2     0    0     5     3     3    0     4    16    0     4     1    3     0    0    2    2     4
5    hsa-miR-127 ID3   29    17    6    55    40    35    6    20   171   10    32    21   23    25   10   14   32    55
```

Summary of original data:

```
> str(ClusterMatrix)
'data.frame':   113 obs. of  98 variables:
 $ miRNA: Factor w/ 202 levels "hsa-miR-106a",..: 1 3 4 6 8 8 14 15 15 16 ...
 $ ID   : Factor w/ 27 levels "ID1","ID10","ID11",..: 25 12 12 12 21 21 12 21 21 6 ...
 $ 100G : Factor w/ 308 levels "-0.307749042739963",..: 279 11 3 3 101 42 139 158 215 222 ...
 $ 100R : Factor w/ 316 levels "-0.138028803567403",..: 207 7 8 8 18 42 128 183 232 209 ...
 $ 106G : Factor w/ 260 levels "-0.103556709881933",..: 171 4 1 3 7 258 95 110 149 162 ...
 $ 106R : Factor w/ 300 levels "-0.141810346640204",..: 141 4 6 2 108 41 146 196 244 267 ...
 $ 122G : Factor w/ 336 levels "-0.0409548922061764",..: 237 12 4 6 103 47 148 203 257 264 ...
 $ 122R : Factor w/ 316 levels "-0.135708706475279",..: 177 1 8 6 36 44 131 192 239 244 ...
 $ 124G : Factor w/ 267 levels "-0.348439853247856",..: 210 5 2 3 7 50 126 138 188 249 ...
 $ 124R : Factor w/ 303 levels "-0.176414190219115",..: 193 3 7 3 21 52 167 200 238 239 ...
 $ 126G : Factor w/ 307 levels "-0.227658806811544",..: 122 88 5 76 169 61 240 220 281 265 ...
 $ 126R : Factor w/ 249 levels "-0.271925865853123",..: 119 1 2 3 11 247 78 110 151 193 ...
 $ 134G : Factor w/ 344 levels "-0.106333543799583",..: 304 14 8 5 33 48 150 196 248 231 ...
 $ 134R : Factor w/ 300 levels "-0.0997616469801097",..: 183 5 7 7 22 298 113 159 213 221 ...
 $ 141G : Factor w/ 335 levels "-0.134429748398679",..: 253 7 3 3 24 29 142 137 223 302 ...
 $ 141R : Factor w/ 314 levels "-0.143299688877927",..: 210 4 5 7 98 54 154 199 255 251 ...
 $ 167G : Factor w/ 306 levels "-0.211181452126958",..: 222 7 4 6 11 292 91 101 175 226 ...
 $ 167R : Factor w/ 282 levels "-0.0490740880560127",..: 130 2 6 4 15 282 110 146 196 197 ...
 $ 185G : Factor w/ 317 levels "-0.0567841338235346",..: 218 2 7 7 33 34 130 194 227 259 ...
```

Comment: I guess you meant `mean`.  But the 'ID" is non-numeric..  Perhaps you might be looking for `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean), 3:ncol(df1))`  If you need to add new columns in the original dataset, use `mutate_each` instead of `summarise_each` and then cbind with the original dataset (`bind_cols`)

Comment: Could you post it as an answer? It seems to work, however, the output is a little weird: Variables not shown: 141G (dbl), 141R (dbl)

Comment: It is just a printing issue with tbl_df.  You can convert to 'data.frame'  and it will show all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  We group by 'ID', use `mutate_each` to create columns that show the `mean` value of '100G' to '185R'.  We select the columns in `mutate_each` by using regex patterns in `matches`.  Then `cbind` (`bind_cols`) the original dataset with the `mutate`d columns, and convert to `data.frame` if needed.  We can also change the column names of the `mean` columns.

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>%
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), matches('^\\d+')) %>%
        setNames(., c(names(.)[1:2], paste0('Mean_', names(.)[3:ncol(.)]))) %>%
        as.data.frame()

out1 <- bind_cols(df1, out[-(1:2)])
out1
#           miRNA  ID 100G 100R 106G 106R 122G 122R 124G 124R 126G 126R 134G
#1   hsa-miR-106a ID7 1585  423  180  113  598  266  227  242   70  106 2703
#2 hsa-miR-1185-1 ID2   10    1    3    3   11    8    4    4   28    2   13
#3 hsa-miR-1185-2 ID2    2    0    2    1    5    1    1    0    4    1    1
#4   hsa-miR-1197 ID2    2    0    0    5    3    3    0    4   16    0    4
#5    hsa-miR-127 ID3   29   17    6   55   40   35    6   20  171   10   32
#  134R 141G 141R 167G 167R 185G 185R   Mean_100G   Mean_100R  Mean_106G
#1  442  715  309  546  113  358  309 1585.000000 423.0000000 180.000000
#2    3    6    3    6    4    7    5    4.666667   0.3333333   1.666667
#3    1    3    2    2    0    2    1    4.666667   0.3333333   1.666667
#4    1    3    0    0    2    2    4    4.666667   0.3333333   1.666667
#5   21   23   25   10   14   32   55   29.000000  17.0000000   6.000000
#  Mean_106R  Mean_122G Mean_122R  Mean_124G  Mean_124R Mean_126G Mean_126R
#1       113 598.000000       266 227.000000 242.000000        70       106
#2         3   6.333333         4   1.666667   2.666667        16         1
#3         3   6.333333         4   1.666667   2.666667        16         1
#4         3   6.333333         4   1.666667   2.666667        16         1
#5        55  40.000000        35   6.000000  20.000000       171        10
#  Mean_134G  Mean_134R Mean_141G  Mean_141R  Mean_167G Mean_167R  Mean_185G
#1      2703 442.000000       715 309.000000 546.000000       113 358.000000
#2         6   1.666667         4   1.666667   2.666667         2   3.666667
#3         6   1.666667         4   1.666667   2.666667         2   3.666667
#4         6   1.666667         4   1.666667   2.666667         2   3.666667
#5        32  21.000000        23  25.000000  10.000000        14  32.000000
#   Mean_185R
#1 309.000000
#2   3.333333
#3   3.333333
#4   3.333333
#5  55.000000
```

EDIT: If we need a single row `mean` for each 'ID', we can use `summarise_each`

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), matches('^\\d+'))
```

EDIT2:  Based on the OP's update the original dataset ('ClusterMatrix') columns are all `factor` class.  We need to convert the columns to `numeric` class before getting the `mean`.  There are two options to convert the `factor` to `numeric` - 1) by `as.numeric(as.character(..` which may be a bit slower, 2) `as.numeric(levels(..` which is faster.  Here I am using the first method as it may be more clear.

```
ClusterMatrix %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(mean= mean(as.numeric(as.character(.)), 
            na.rm=TRUE)), matches('^\\d+'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(miRNA = c("hsa-miR-106a", "hsa-miR-1185-1",
"hsa-miR-1185-2", 
"hsa-miR-1197", "hsa-miR-127"), ID = c("ID7", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID3"), `100G` = c(1585L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 29L), `100R` = c(423L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 17L), `106G` = c(180L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 6L), `106R` = c(113L, 
3L, 1L, 5L, 55L), `122G` = c(598L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 40L), `122R` = c(266L, 
8L, 1L, 3L, 35L), `124G` = c(227L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L), `124R` = c(242L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 20L), `126G` = c(70L, 28L, 4L, 16L, 171L), `126R` = c(106L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 10L), `134G` = c(2703L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 32L), `134R` = c(442L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 21L), `141G` = c(715L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 23L), `141R` = c(309L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 25L), `167G` = c(546L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 10L), `167R` = c(113L, 
4L, 0L, 2L, 14L), `185G` = c(358L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 32L), `185R` = c(309L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 55L)), .Names = c("miRNA", "ID", "100G", "100R", 
"106G", "106R", "122G", "122R", "124G", "124R", "126G", "126R", 
"134G", "134R", "141G", "141R", "167G", "167R", "185G", "185R"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
))
```

Comment: Error in cbind_all(list(x, ...)) : object '.' not found

Comment: nice. what was the bug?

Comment: @user2300940 I updated the post.  May be there was some typo or so.

Comment: I think maybe you miss-understood the original question. I would like to merge the lines with similar IDs and then take the average value across all samples. The output should then be one line for each ID. Or maybe you did this, just that the output shows all lines?

Comment: @user2300940 In that case just replace `mutate_each` with `summarise_each` and do not need the `bind_cols`

Comment: Looks good. However, I dont know how the average of the column 100G for ID12 could be 141.0000 when the two values are 5.78106642602862 and 18.4516868951815

Comment: @user2300940 I guess that must be in your original dataset as the example didn't show `ID12`.  It seems strange for me.  Is there any leading/lagging spaces in the 'ID' column?   Can you check the `class` of the `100G` column? Is it numeric?  i.e. `str(yourdata)`

Comment: The calculations are wrong for every column. Please see update in the question.

Comment: @user2300940  I can see why you got wrong.  The columns are all `factor` class. We have to convert the columns to `numeric` first.

Comment: @user2300940  Try `ClusterMatrix %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean= mean(as.numeric(as.character(.)), na.rm=TRUE)), matches('^\\d+'))`